# Subsetting rows in R data.table based on conditional values for multiple variables

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I am interested in doing calculations on only the subset of rows that have the same value for two specific variables, and two different values for another variable.

For this toy dataset:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5), 
            y = c(10,10,10,10,24,24,26,26,51,51,51,34,34,34,34,65,65,65,65,65),
            z = c('m', 'm', 'f', 'f', 'b', 'b', 'm', 'm', 'b', 'b', 'b', 
            'm', 'm', 'f', 'f', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'))
```

I am only interested in the rows in which for a given x value and y value, z equals 'm' and 'f'. So in this table, I need a script that will extract rows where x=1 and x=4, since these are the only rows where y remains constant and z has both 'f' and 'm' values. If z has a 'b' value, or only 'f' OR 'm', I don't need it.

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially checking if all `z`'s are `m/f` and all `m/f` are represented in `z`. So:

```
DT[, if(all(z %in% c("m","f")) & all(c("m","f") %in% z)) .SD,  by=.(x,y)]
```

As @Frank wisely suggests in the comments, this is `setequal`, so:

```
DT[, if(setequal(z, c("m","f"))) .SD,  by=.(x,y)]

#   x  y z
#1: 1 10 m
#2: 1 10 m
#3: 1 10 f
#4: 1 10 f
#5: 4 34 m
#6: 4 34 m
#7: 4 34 f
#8: 4 34 f
```

Answer (score 2):

since you are looking at whether `y` did not change and that z contains both `m` and `f` we will use `all(c("m","f")%in%z)` to see whether z contains both m and f and use `table(y)==.N` or `length(unique(y))==1` to indicate that `y` did not change. then merge it back to the data and then subset

```
DT[DT,s := table(y)==.N & all(z %in% c("m","f")),on = "x",by = .EACHI][s==T][,s := NULL][]
   x  y z
1: 1 10 m
2: 1 10 m
3: 1 10 f
4: 1 10 f
5: 4 34 m
6: 4 34 m
7: 4 34 f
8: 4 34 f
```

for a tidyverse format:

```
DT%>%
   group_by(x)%>%
    filter(length(unique(y)) == 1 & all(z %in% c("m","f")))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   x [2]
      x     y z    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1    1.   10. m    
2    1.   10. m    
3    1.   10. f    
4    1.   10. f    
5    4.   34. m    
6    4.   34. m    
7    4.   34. f    
8    4.   34. f
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks so much. Just did that